# Same functionality with $.grep() as $(' ').filter();

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

How can i achive the same functionality?

> **Filter:**
>
> response_status = $(server_response).filter("response_status").val();
>
> **Grep:**
>
> response_status =$.grep($(server_response), function (value, i){
>   return (value.indexOf('response_status') == -1);});

Unfortunately this line just keep telling me, that `indexOf()` `TypeError: value.indexOf is not a function`, and have no idea why.

And i have a jquery ajax call where i want to use this compatibility, my related code part:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'ajax.php',
         contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-2",
    data:{p1:p1,
          }})
    .done(function(server_response) {
        response_status = $(server_response).filter("response_status").val();
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting indexOf() is not a function, then it means that your server response is not of String type. Please check the type of 'value' before executing indexOf() on it.

Comment: true, because my server_response is an array : S

Comment: but if you see this example, also used as an array:
http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1613-how-to-filter-arrays-with-jquery-grep/, top of that the value is not a function not server_response

Comment: To debug this issue i will suggest you to add some more log statement inside .done handler. First of all try to print the type of 'server_response' variable. Then check try printing entire contents of this varibale

Comment: thanks, i think it is a html node type element. But how can i know sure?
??Object.prototype.toString.apply(t)??

Comment: Instead of finding exact type of 'server_response' variable i think its better to add content type in your ajax request like below:
`$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'ajax.php',
         contentType: 'application/json'`
By this way you will alway get JSON response in done handler and if server is sending back Array then your grep function should work similar to oreilly example